# I want to design android application page with add and remove option

Tags: android

I want to use add(+) and remove(-) items option in my e-commerce shopping application. when i add new item, it should display price. Incase of adding one more time the same item must display 2*price. how can i do it

Comment: they are just buttons. are you able to do that with normal buttons?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this simply using Buttons and saving the values in either `SharedPreferences` or `SQLite`